# Embed TeamViewer inside UWP app in Windows 10 Kiosk mode

Tags: uwp, windows-10, kiosk, teamviewer

I have a requirement to open TeamViewer from my UWP app in **Windows 10 Kiosk** mode.

I can launch TeamViewer using LaunchURIAsync method (using URL protocol - **teamviewer10**). As expected it minimize my UWP app and opens the TeamViewer as separate app in full screen mode in Kiosk user.

And I know in Kiosk mode only one app can be shown at a time and it will be the top most app. But I need to show the TeamViewer on top of my UWP app.

Is there any way to achieve it? Or can we embed the TeamViewer inside UWP dialog?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't embed an external win32 application into a UWP application, you can only call it via the URL protocol, as you do.

Comment: I'm currently writing a kiosk app myself and one of the next requirements is TeamViewer integration. I agree, there has to be a way to do this.

Comment: Hi, if you need to embed an external exe application into your current application, you may want to consider using Win32 applications to achieve your goals. Because UWP does not allow embedding in external applications.

Comment: Thanks Richard. But as I mentioned, need to show from UWP app in MultiKiosk without minimizing my app. Seems it is not possible now.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. But this can be analogized to mobile apps. Under normal circumstances, only one app will be displayed on the screen. After exiting the app, it will only return to the desktop instead of opening the previous app.